# After computing the hash, what is the significance of keeping the only the last byte of the hash

Tags: python-3.x, hash, machine-learning, hashcode

`Problem: To generate Test and train to improve on Generalization error.` 
possible solutions: 
1. Split instances into train 80% and test 20%, train your model on trainset and tests on testset. But repeating above again and again will somehow let the model cram the data as in multiple time splits will select 1st time chosen instances of the testset into trainset(random sampling.)

The above approach might fail when we fetch an updated dataset.
Another approach is to select each instance's most stable feature/s(combination can be) to create a unique & immutable identifier that will remain robust even after the dataset updates.After selecting one, we could compute a hash of each instance's identifier, keep only the last two bytes of the hash, and put the instance in the test set if the value is <= 256 * test_ratio.}. This will ensure that testset will remain consistent across multiple runs, even if the dataset is refreshed.

```
Question: What is the significance of just taking last two bytes of the computed hash?
```

Answer (score 1):

-----Thanks to Aurélien Géron-------

We need a solution to sample a unique test-set even after fetching a updated dataset.
`SOLUTION: to use each instance's identifier to decide whether or not it should go to test_set.{Assuming that the instances have a unique and immutable identifier. 
 we could compute a hash of each instance's identifier, keep only the last bytes of the hash, and put the instance in the test set if value is <= 256*test_ratio i.e 51}`

This ensures that the test-set will remain consistent across multiple runs, even if you refresh the dataset. The new test_set will contain 20% of the new instances, but it will not contain any instance that was previosly in the train_set. 
First, a quick recap on hash functions:

- `A hash function f(x) is deterministic, such that if a==b, then f(a)==f(b)`.
- Moreover, if `a!=b`, then with a very high probability `f(a)!=f(b)`.
  With this definition, a function such as `f(x)=x%12345678` (where % is the modulo operator) meets the criterion above, so it is technically a hash function.However, most hash functions go beyond this definition, and they act more or less like pseudo-random number generators, so if you compute `f(1), f(2), f(3),...,` the output will look very much like a random sequence of (usually very large) numbers.

We can use such a "random-looking" hash function to split a dataset into a train set and a test set.

Let's take the MD5 hash function, for example. It is a random-looking hash function, but it outputs rather large numbers (128 bits), such as `136159519883784104948368321992814755841`.

For a given instance in the dataset, there is 50% chance that its MD5 hash will be smaller than 2^127 (assuming the hashes are unsigned integers), and a 25% chance that it will be smaller than 2^126, and a 12.5% chance that it will be smaller than 2^125. So if I want to split the dataset into a train set and a test set, with 87.5% of the instances in the train set, and 12.5% in the test set, then all I need to do is to compute the MD5 hash of some unchanging features of the instances, and put the instances whose MD5 hash is smaller than 2^125 into the test set.

If I want precisely 10% of the instances to go into the test set, then I need to check`MD5 < 2^128 * 10 / 100`.
This would work fine, and you can definitely implement it this way if you want. However, it means manipulating large integers, which is not always very convenient, especially given that Python's hashlib.md5() function outputs byte arrays, not long integers. So it's simpler to just take one or two bytes in the hash (anywhere you wish), and convert them to a regular integer. If you just take one byte, it will look like a random number from 0 to 255.
If you want to have 10% of the instances in the test set, you just need to check that the byte is smaller or equal to 25. It won't be exactly 10%, but actually `26/256=10.15625%`, but that's close enough. If you want a higher precision, you can take 2 or more bytes.